# Delay a modal load after X seconds using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am able to load a bootstrap modal on page load, just want to know how to load modal X seconds after page loads? This is my code so far.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Javascript:

[setTimeout(function,delayInMiliSeconds)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){$('#myModal').modal('show');},3000); \\Executes after 3 seconds
    });
</script>
```

---

Jquery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').delay(3000).modal('show'); \\same as above
    });
</script>
```

---